# Unable to Connect Tableau with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, odbc, tableau-api

I was trying to connect Tableau with Cassandra.

Tableau version: 10.0(I also tried 8.3)

Cassandra version: 3.0.8

DataStax Enterprise Server 5.0.2

I installed Datastax ODBC driver 2.4 (64 bit), and configured DSN(Data Source Name). The connection to Cassandra was successful when I tested from ODBC Data Source Administrator. 
[image]

But when I tried to connect from Tableau, I got this error: [image]

I was able to connect to Cassandra from Datastax DevCenter, so I think the problem is either on Tableau end or the driver itself.

I tried both 10.0 and 8.3 version of Tableau, neither work.

Here are the error logs from Datastax ODBC driver:

Oct 14 14:25:04.869 ERROR 5376 Statement::SQLPrepareW: [DataStax][CassandraODBC] (10) Error while executing a query in Cassandra: [33562624] : line 1:7 no viable alternative at input '1' (SELECT [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a11uV.png))

Oct 14 14:39:56.491 ERROR 6112 Statement::SQLPrepareW: [DataStax][CassandraODBC] (10) Error while executing a query in Cassandra: [33562624] : line 1:7 no viable alternative at input '1' (SELECT [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a11uV.png))

Seems like ODBC driver was not able to compose the right CQL query.

Can someone help me ? Thanks

I followed this instruction: 
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-odbc-cql-connector-apache-cassandra-datastax-enterprise

Answer (score 1):

When you select “Other Databases (ODBC)” in Tableau and choose the DSN you created, make sure to fill out the Server, Port, and Database fields.

AS the error says the server's permission settings could also be a factor.

Also, once you connect to the server, in the Data Source tab manually type in schema name which your keyspace +  to add to Tableau and then in the table field type in your table name and click +

Comment: I was able to connect Cassandra from DevCenter, shouldn't be permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

The ODBC Driver isn't supported for DSE 5.0.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/common/driverMatrix.html

Comment: but from the document, the driver I use do support Cassandra 3.0.8 (the version I use). https://downloads.datastax.com/odbc-cql/2.4.1.1001/Simba%20ODBC%20Driver%20for%20Cassandra%20Install%20Guide.pdf